# How can I change projection of a co-ordinate?

Tags: coordinate-system, utm, transverse-mercator

I want to convert a known co-ordinate which is in UTM projection to transverse mercator projection. I know the central meridian, scale factor, false easting, false northing value. Can someone give me some insight how can I convert this?

As for example, my known co-ordinate is UTM Easting 778582.17 and 
UTM Northing 2671407.66. I want to convert it in following projection:

Projection: Transverse Mercator

False Easting: 500000.0

False Northing: -2000000.0

Central Meridian: 90

Scale factor: 0.9996

Latitude of origin: 0.0

Linear Unit: Meter

Datum: WGS 84

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I have recently installed expertgps by topografix. Can I perform it with this software? @MichaelStimson

Comment: utm is already a transverse mercator projection. I would suggest you'll find the epsg codes of both your reference systems (input and output) and then find the converter of your choice on google

Comment: This is just my delusional theory...You are trying to convert from UTM46N(EPSG:32646) to Modified Gulshan303 (EPSG;3106). If so please try [EPSG.io transformation](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=32646&t_srs=3106) to convert your XY and then compensate manually the `+y_0=-2000000` (Because Gulshan 303 is `+y_0=0`).

Comment: That is not software I am aware of. You could perform this transformation in python with GDAL/OGR by creating a proj.4 string from your parameters.. the only information you're missing is what source UTM are you referring to? Is that WGS84 UTM Zone 46 North? (central meridian 93, EPSG 32646). UTM is an acronym for Universal *Transverse Mercator*, which has many zones http://www.jaworski.ca/utmzones.htm so it's important to know which zone your input data as UTM is in to convert to TM with a nonstandard CM/false northing.